# materials not showing in viewport (blender 2.8 on macbook pro)

Tags: rendering, osx

I have an issue with blender 2.8 BETA. In viewport I can see materials I made in 2.79 and switch among them but I can't see any changes I make in 2.8. I can't create any new materials using nodes to be seen in viewport. All the changes CAN BE SEEN in rendered picture. I can see changes in material when I turn off "USE NODES"

I have Mcbook Pro 13-inch, 2016, 2,9 GHz Intel Core i5,Intel Iris Graphics 550

blender-2.80.0-git20190215.faa255c0a4e4-x86_64

I have tested it on PC and it worked perfectly,
Thank you

[image]

Comment: I found I'm having the same problem as well. Check the Material "Preview" panel -- is it showing anything (like a circle or sphere) or is it just a big grey rectangle?

Comment: Here's a screen shot of the problem for me, too: http://www.neopics.com/images/Blender-2.80-on-macOS.jpg

Comment: Same here. But if I make a copy of a material, it appears. Since this is happening neither on PC nor on iMac where I tried 2.8, I assume this is a bug that can be fixed in next version. I haven't found any other solution so far.